# Display date with a hard coded day

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

[image]

I need to hardcode the day value to '01'. So, the expected output should be:

```
NULL
20081001
20081201
20080901
20070901
20080601
20070201
....
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [EOMONTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead of hardcore value `1`:

```
select dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(date, -1))
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--You can Use the YEAR and MONTH functions and cast them 
--to varchar and concat them together with '01' as the day on the end
--with CASE on month in case it is single digit month, prepend zero

SELECT CAST(YEAR([Date]) AS varchar(10)) + CASE WHEN MONTH([Date]) < 10 THEN '0' + CAST(MONTH([Date]) AS varchar(2)) ELSE CAST(MONTH([Date]) AS varchar(2)) END + '01' AS [HardCodedDate]
FROM [Table]
```

Comment: @Larnu No worries.

Answer (score 0):

The `DATEDIFF` and `DATEADD` method works here too:

```
DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,[date]),0)
```